# Sprite kit get access to child nodes in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I need to get access to child nodes of the `SKSpriteNode` .
In iOS 9.1 I used to do like this:

```
let node = nodeAtPoint(touchLocation)

If let myNode = node as? MyNode {
//some code if node is kind of class
```

It worked perfectly, but in iOS 9.2 it doesn't. Anyone knows what is the matter?

Comment: How doesn't it work? - are you getting an error?

Comment: `if let` along with `as!` does not work

Comment: of, my mistake, the code is



If let myNode = node as? MyNode {
//some code if node is kind of class



but it doesn't work anyway
No errors, it just cant recognise that node is type of class

Comment: Have you tried printing the node to see what it is? `print(node)`

Comment: are you sure that node is a member of MyNode?  maybe it is pulling in the parent node,  and your zorder needs to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

To access an SKNode's children access the read-only 'children' parameter (see [SKNode children](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKNode/children)).

I suspect the iOS 9.1 to 9.2 change is misleading. nodeAtPoint will only return a child if it happens also to be located at that point and regardless of its sub-class. If more than one node exists it chooses the 'deapest' and then the 'largest z' (if all have the same z what it returns it presumably arbitrary). If no nodes exist at that point it returns the receiver. So what it returns is highly variable depending on your scene at the instant it is called - so it may have appeared to be working when it was never really doing what you thought?